# Passing extra parameters to an event handler defined elsewhere?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a general use SQL utility class I wrote for a lot of tasks and I use the SQLInfoMessageEventHandler to display Error/Information messages from long running stored procedures.

I'd like my event handler delegate (which is defined outside the class) to be able to get extra information such as the string `storedProcedureName`. Is there a clean way to do this?

I have multiple utility classes that I'm trying to keep separate so I don't to display any messages from within the SQL class as I use a different class to display/log events.

I've seen some pretty clever methods on here using Lambda expressions but I can figure out how to make it work when I define the delegate outside my class.

```
//SQL class method
executeQuery (string storedProcedureName, SqlnfoMessageEventHandler eh = null)
{
    //setup SQL connection
    if (eh ! null)
    {
        connection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
        connection.InfoMessage += eh;
    }
    //finish work
}


//Outside SQL class
static void showInfoMessage (object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    //Display e.Message
    //Would also like to receive the storedProcedureName string
}
```

Comment: Then why not add an extra property inside `SqlInfoMessageEventArgs` or derive a class from it... Your code is not complete and miss some useful information.

Comment: I can't derive from the Microsoft SQL classes as they are sealed - even if I could derive new classes - I think that's at least 3 (SqlInfoMessageHandler,SqlConnection,Sqlcommand) that I would have to derive to add the additional information.

I was hoping there was a more generic way to work around this.

Comment: Then why are reusing their handler?